# Quickly Validate Form Fields in PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation

When I have fields under a `form` tag, I use `isset()` function such as below:

```
if(isset($_POST) and isset($_POST['title']) and $_POST['date'])
{
   //something;
}
```

and it gets bigger when I validate more fields. I am looking for any easy way of validate whether they are all filled or not in server-side with PHP.

Maybe something which navigates all the fields and check whether they are filled as required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$fields = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3', ...etc...); //  Array of fields

$valid = true;  //Assume all fields are correct and set this to false if not

foreach($fields as $field) {
    if(!array_key_exits($field, $_POST)) { 
        $valid = false; // At least one key isn't set
        break;
    }
}

if($valid) {
    // All fields are good
} else {
    //Your user failed...
}
```

Comment: You have to reset the $array before using array_key_exists 
`reset($array);
array_key_exists($needle,$array);`

Comment: And also, it is not built-in function. It should be `array_key_exists` .

Comment: @Braveyard: Actually, you don't. Also, he is using `array_keyS_exists()` (plural)!

Comment: @hakre: yeah but it seems it doesn't accept an array as a key.

Comment: Adjusted my answer a bit. The original was using a function I used a while ago. Principle is the same though

Comment: @hakre: Is it? The arguments don't look right if he meant `array_key_exists()`.

Comment: @Braveyard, Alix Axel: My fault, mixed it, Mike did already corrected my mis-edit. @Mike: Yeah, just for leaving me and edit ;)

Comment: I've recently found a problem with this logic since if all the keys are declared under `<form>` tag, that means they are all set but they might be empty and that's what I am checking actually (required). So the code should be checking whether they are empty or not instead of being set.

Comment: so do something like `if(!array_key_exits($field, $_POST) && isset($_POST[$field]))`

Answer (score 4):

```
// required fields
$fields = array('title', 'date', 'email');

// optionally ignore blank posted values
$_POST = array_filter(array_map('trim', $_POST), 'strlen');

if (count(array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($fields))) == count($fields))
{
    // all the required fields were posted
}

else
{
    // ...not
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is an array, so you can fetch its element using `foreach` and then test each element if it is empty or no, collecting errors if there and at the end send one error message.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it amongst comment section on PHP Manual...

A little function which take an array as keys:

```
<?php
//note the s in the function name (keys)
function array_keys_exists($array,$keys) {
    foreach($keys as $k) {
        if(!isset($array[$k])) {
        return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
?>
//useful to validate a form for example
<form>
    <input type="text" name="field1" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="field2" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="field3" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="field4" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="field5" /><br />
</form>
<?php
if(!array_keys_exists($_POST,
array("field1","field2","field3","field4","field5")
)) {
    //some fields are missing, dont do anything (maybe hacking)
} else {
    //code ...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more reusable solution would be to write a small function to verify a list of keys exist, such as

```
function array_keys_exist($keys, $search) {
    // If we were passed a single key, use existing function
    if (!is_array($keys)) {
        return array_key_exists($keys, $search);
    }
    // If there are no keys in $search that are not in $keys
    // We have all the keys
    return 0 == count(array_diff($keys, array_keys($search)));
}
```

which could then be used for all your forms like this:

```
$requiredFields = array('title', 'date', 'details');
if (array_keys_exist($requiredFields, $_POST)) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

Frankly, I'm not sure why this isn't already a built-in function